# Can you help me understand the assertion about node js thread(s)?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, linkedin-api, threadpool, libuv

#### Backstory

I recently completed my Node.js skill assessment on LinkedIn, which is basically a small test. But i noticed a question with a weird answer, which i can not understand.

#### Question

> How does it affect the performance of a web application when an execution path contains a CPU-heavy operation, such as calculating a long Fibonacci sequence?

#### Right answer

> The current thread will block until the executon is completed **and the operating system will spawn new threads to handle incoming requests.** This can exhaust the number of allowed threads (255) and degrade performance over time.

### Problem

I always thought that node is not creating a new threads unless you're using something like `child-process` or workers. I tried to create a simple express server with one endpoint, that is blocking execution forever:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('recieved request');

  while (true) {}
});
```

And when i tried to send multiple requests, only one log message has appeared, which means that new thread is not created to handle new request.

So, is this answer just incorrect (even though it seems as a correct one), or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your code will do the get then the while loop will run forever preventing to go any further.

Comment: Yes, i understand it. But assertion says that the operating system will spawn new threads to handle incoming requests, and this confuses me

Comment: But you said it. "The current thread will block until the executon is completed". Once its completed, the next request will run in a new thread. As long as it's not completed, it won't create a new thread. JS is single threaded.

Comment: But in this case, what is the point of creating a new thread, if execution in previous thread is already completed?

Comment: Well, all the resources used (memory etc) will be released when the thread ends. You start "fresh" with a new thread.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But what about  **the number of allowed threads (255)**? How is that related to this model

Comment: Those threads are not going to run unless the blocking one is done, then will run in order of creation. If you have 255 requests jammed because of the blocking request, then there will be no thread left for new requests.